# PHP strtotime with output from Bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, date, datetime, datepicker

Bootstrap time picker gives me Date in this format:

```
Mon Mar 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

I would like to use it as a Date object in PHP.

I am attempting to use it like:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s" , strtotime("Mon Mar 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"));
```

But that results in:

```
1969-12-31 18:00:00
```

Which I understand to be pretty close to EPOCH.

I'm thinking I'm either using the wrong function, or I formatted date() wrong.

I am using the TimePicker from [here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org).

Answer (score 1):

strtotime only works on certain formats of which can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

```
Mar 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500
```

The above portion should return the right time value for you.  Either change the way that the picker is outputting the date, without knowing which picker I will assume its this one http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format or do some string manipulation on the current date format from the picker (the first option would be simpler and easier to read).

Comment: Hmm... So I should simply do `$time = strstr('Mon Mar 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)', ' (');`?

Comment: I would change the format outputted by the bootstrap date picker to match one of the date formats listed in the php manual.  Once that happens you should just be able to pass the output from the datepicker directly to strtotime